# Selection panel - javascript radio button groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, radio-group

I'm looking for a way to modify a page like this> 
http://speckyboy.com/demo/digg-style-radio-buttons/index.html
so users can highlight one selection per row, IOW 8 radio button groups using a comparable visual style, not the traditional looking radio button controls.

I've tried nearly all the suggestions in stackoverflow I could find for handling radio button groups the last few days, but I clearly don't know enough js to adapt those suggestions properly. Can anyone help?

Comment: Group them using the `name` attribute http://jsfiddle.net/SZ2EU/

Answer (score 1):

You should use class(not ID, id must be unique on the page).

1  You can get all radio buttons

```
$('.class')
```

2  Now you can use `each` More details here http://api.jquery.com/each/

```
 $('.class').each(function(index) {
       // Add to element
    });
```

3 To add you can with

http://api.jquery.com/add/

http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

http://api.jquery.com/append/

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the same id for all the radio buttons so that they work as a single entity? Then you can place them wherever you like.

Comment: All the radio buttons have the same id, currently, which is why only one out of all those selectable text strings is highlighted. I'm trying to find a way to select one in each row, so the ultimately, in that specific page's layout, 8 elements (1 per row) could be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a class for your elements - not sure if you were using radio buttons in the background or not like the example you posted

Minimized html

```
<div id='group1' class='radio'>
Group 1
<input type='radio' name='test'/> 
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <a href='#' class='c'>group 1a</a>   
</div>​
```

jQuery

```
$('.row a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.addClass('sel') // add class to currently clicked anchor
        .siblings() // get siblings
        .removeClass('sel'); // remove class from siblings

   $('.radio').eq($('.row').index($this.parent())) // <-- get row of radios equal to this row
              .find('input[type=radio]') // find the inputs radios under this
              .eq($this.index()) // get radio with same index as clicked anchor
              .click(); // trigger click
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lupw9/

Comment: OMG! Thanks so much, wirey, especially for the JSFiddle view. I just started learning js, but sweet little book examples to address basic concepts is never as help as much as examining real implementations to study how they tick.

Comment: @user1729539 np.. :)  It's fun programming!!  Don't forget to accept answer if it answers your question